# Write a comma in a CSV File with PHP

Tags: php, csv

i am sending a csv file as a header and i want to use a comma (not to seperate, just to use). how would i do that?
i'm using PHP and i can not use `fputcsv` because i'm sending it as a header.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just use `'"'.$value.'"'` around it and it will be fine.

Comment: When adding quotes around a field you'll also have to remember to escape quotes _in_ the field! Usr str_replace for that.

Answer (score 9):

Either write the CSV to file first and then send it via [`readfile`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) or write it to the output stream directly:

```
fputcsv(
    fopen('php://output', 'w+'),
    array(
        'Some text',
        'Some text with commas ,,,,,',
        'Other text'
    )
);
```

which will then print

```
"Some text","Some text with commas ,,,,,","Other text"
```

Note that [`fputcsv`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) will also allow you to change delimiters and enclosures, so in addition to just wrapping the value in quotes you can also just change the delimiter to, for instance, a semicolon.

See the PHP Manual on supported wrappers in [`fopen`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php):

- http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php