# creating csv file with php with inserted commas

Tags: php, csv

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Write a comma in a CSV File with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7545733/write-a-comma-in-a-csv-file-with-php)

I am creating a csv file with php with this simple code:

```
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-control: private');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
    header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="positionsCountryReport.csv"');
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');


    apache_setenv('no-gzip', 0);
    @ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 1);
    @ini_set('implicit_flush', 1);
    for ($i = 0; $i < ob_get_level(); $i++) { @ob_end_flush(); }
    ob_implicit_flush(1);
```

than for placingdata in to cells I simply use "echo" and the data that I want to place.
for moving to the nexr cell I am echoing "," a comma.

I now need to place commas inside my cells, but when I do that...
it displays to the next cell instead of comma.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7545733/write-a-comma-in-a-csv-file-with-php?rq=1